# Confusion about relation between Temperature and Resistance

Tags: thermodynamics, electrical-resistance

we know that

T = $\  triple .point.temperature * \tfrac{Resistance. at. temperature. T}{Resistance .at. triple. point}$  (1)

and

[image](2)

we can assume [image] = temperature at triple point

and [image] is coefficient of temperature .

in equation (1) we dont need any coefficient of temperature to relate temperature and resistance  but in equation (2) we are bringing a co-efficient.

if we need a co-efficient then why dont we use it in the 1st equation where temperature and resistance at triple point are considered as initial temperature and resistance.

i mean what's the relation between two equations?

both equation represent the same relation between temperature and resistance.but why are they different?  (for example first equation has no co-efficient )

Comment: You can just relate them by some basic math. But I would advise you to formulate your "question" a bit more understandable.

Comment: A few hints: It would help to write a) where those relations come from, b) what the symbols mean and c) to do some math to obtain the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easy to solve this puzzle dont assume $R_0$ to be anything, Just use $R$ and $R_T$ for resistance at current temperature $(T)$ and at triple point $(T_T)$.

now

$R-R_0=R_0\alpha(T-T_0)$ and

$R_T-R_0=R_0\alpha(T_T-T_0)$

now divide two expressions and do some basic math and you will get equaiton 1